# Is there anyway to retrieve the URL of videos uploaded to youtube with Everyplay?

Tags: c#, youtube, unity-game-engine, everyplay

Hello all I recently downloaded  and opened the unity package for everyplay android and wanted to know is there anyway I could grab the URL of videos uploaded to youtube by  users who play my game ? it looks like the majority of the code for the actual share functionality is external and I am not seeing any functions that return a URL string .

Comment: Just an update for anyone looking for similar functionality after I contacted EveryPlay , they stated that  they currently don't have the feature or ability to retrieve the URL from uploaded videos .  I imagine they  are using a service like youtube instant to upload the video after rendering it out and just passing the render data to the video

Answer (score 0):

Just search Youtube "{gamename} replay: {score} points in {level_name}!" Replace with your info then copy that url and add to your game. That is the default EveryPlay title applied to uploaded videos unless you change it.

You can change it to {gamename} EveryPlay Replay

Then when you search you tube for your game name EveryPlay Replay you will see all uploaded videos with default title. Hope this helps.